# Migrate domain name to VPS

Tags: domain-name-system, vps, bind, nameserver

Because I'm relatively inexperienced in working with a VPS, please bear with me for this question.

I am currently in the process of migrating my website from [NearlyFreeSpeech](http://www.nearlyfreespeech.net) to [prgmr](http://www.prgmr.com), and all I have left to do is set up nameservers on my VPS and transfer the domain. Here is where I run into trouble.

I've tried looking up how to create public DNS nameservers on Google, but the little information I found wasn't so useful (setting up private nameservers is all I get). So far, I've created a new nameserver in `bind` and set up a zone file for it, but it doesn't work, so I'll probably scrap it.

Here's what I need to know: is there any documentation on how to do this? Is there a guide or tutorial I can follow to do what I need to do? I'm looking to set up two nameservers (`ns1.itaiferber.com` and `ns2.itaiferber.com`) in `bind`, and then set them as the nameservers for my domain on NearlyFreeSpeech. So far, everything I've found has been less than useful, so any information on the topic would be a great help.

As an addendum: I have very little control over DNS in NearlyFreeSpeech (I can't edit the config file directly, only use a preconfigured web page to manage it), so please take that into account...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to move your DNS to Zonedit or EasyDNS. We use Zoneedit for years, and it makes DNS management **very** easy - and independent of your hosting provider.

Comment: +1 seconded - Use any reasonable third party DNS provider. DNS is a pain to setup and if not done correctly,  will seriously foul things up.

Comment: Great! It worked!